# Unable to determine schema while creating the table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, avro

I am trying to create a hive table using the following query

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table PARTITIONED BY(loaded_stage_date BIGInt)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
location 'hdfs:///dev/data/warehouse/clean/abc/source/tao/bdo/test_table'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///dev/data/warehouse/clean/abc/source/tao/dbo/test_table/.metadata/test_table.avsc');`

The table schema is as follows:

```
{
  "type":"record",
  "name":"test",
  "namespace":"com.abc.def.jhon",
  "doc":"test",
  "fields": [{
                                                "name":"ID",
                                                "type":"string"
                } ,{
                                                "name":"LOGIN_ID",
                                                "type":"string"
                } ,{
                                                "name":"ENAME",
                                                "type":"string"
                } ,{
                                                "name":"STATE",
                                                "type":"string"
                } ,{
                                "name":"LOCAL_START_TIME",
                                "type":"long"
                } ,{
                                "name":"LOCAL_STOP_TIME",
                                "type":"long"
                } ,{
                                "name":"UTC_START_TIME",
                                "type":"long"
                } ,{
                                "name":"UTC_STOP_TIME",
                                "type":"long"
                } ,{
                                "name":"NDX",
                                "type":"long"
                } ,{
                                "name":"STATE_INDX",
                                "type":"float"
                } ,{
                                "name":"GUID",
                                "type":"string"
                } ,{
                                "name":"DURATION_SECONDS",
                                "type":"bigint"
                                  }]
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error_error_error_error_error_error_error       string                  from deserializer
cannot_determine_schema string                  from deserializer
check                   string                  from deserializer
schema                  string                  from deserializer
url                     string                  from deserializer
and                     string                  from deserializer
literal                 string                  from deserializer
loaded_stage_date       bigint
```

> However when I specify the column type as **int** rather than **bigint** in the avsc(schema file) file it runs fine.

Comment: changing the type to "Long" worked....